# Change format datetime in android studio sql server

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

How to change format datetime display in my application from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in my SQL Server format datetime yyyy-mm-dd.

[image]

```
    dateparse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    List<Map<String, String>> listas  = null;
    listas = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    try {

        String querya = "Select * from dsewa";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(querya);


        while (rs.next()) {


            Map<String,String> datatag = new HashMap<String, String>();

            datatag.put("tglbukti", rs.getString("TGLBUKTI"));
            datatag.put("ket1", rs.getString("KET1"));
            datatag.put("ket2", rs.getString("KET2"));
            listas.add(datatag);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", "" + e .getMessage());
    }
    String [] haha = {"tglbukti", "ket1", "ket2"};
    int [] array = {R.id.kaka, R.id.mama, R.id.papa};
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(lihatjadwal.this, listas, R.layout.tampilanlihatjadwal, haha, array);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What Java version are you using? You should really use the modern datetime API `java.time` and create a `LocalDateTime` from the datetime received from the database, which is then formattable at will... The easiest way to do so would be `rs.getTimestamp("TGLBUKTI").toLocalDateTIme()`, but you have to make sure the type of `tglbukti` in the database table is `Timestamp` and your JDBC implementation supports it.

Comment: `timestamp` in SQL Server isn't what you think it is, @deHaar. It's not a date and time datatype.